# show pdf thumbnail in KML balloon

Tags: pdf, kml

I'm trying to revamp a collection of KMLs at work with more "stylish" information balloons.  One of the things I'd like to do is have the balloon show a thumbnail of a PDF located on a web resource.  Is this possible?  I do not want to have to go in to each PDF and create an image then load it separately.  Can KML retrieve a thumbnail?

I've tried using "img src" and "iframe" without success.  Your suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What are you viewing the KML with?

Comment: I am using Google Earth EC.  This is located on company intranet and cannot access the WWW.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google PDF viewer for this purpose. It works very nicely and smoothly when displayed in Google Earth. If PDF is not web accessible then you would need to upload your PDF somewhere and just use its URL in the target of an iframe in the description as illustrated in example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 ...
 <Placemark>
  <description>
   <![CDATA[
   <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://stlab.adobe.com/wiki/images/d/d3/Test.pdf&embedded=true"
    style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>   
   ]]>
  </description>
 </Placemark>
```

Note there's an upper limit to the size of the PDF that can be displayed.
Any PDF with size > 25MB cannot be viewed within Docs Viewer. Smaller PDFs files are viewable as well as MS Power Point (PPT and PPTX) files.